# How to start foreman in production mode(ENV)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

Is it possible run the rails foreman in production mode in local terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Set the `RAILS_ENV` variable to production.

```
$ RAILS_ENV="production" foreman start
```

Answer (score 2):

`RAILS_ENV` env value will be overridden by the `.env` file when foreman starts.

However, you can start foreman with `--env` option:

`foreman start --env .env,production.env`

```
# production.env

RAILS_ENV=production
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=enabled
```

Comment: The .env override part is what was tripping me up! Thanks!